# Spring dynamic @Bean registration with SpringApplicationBuilder failing in test

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

**Trying to register beans dynamically** via **SpringApplicationBuilder** class and it's working when running the app, but when **trying to execute the test** and trying to verify that the beans are defined in the context, **they fail for the dynamic bean**. Feel like I have to use another "magical" annotation for the tests for them to properly load the dynamic beans.

This is the code used and if you run the tests you will see that both cases will fail. BarService will fail also because FooService is registered dynamically via builder, but if you would remove the dependency it will pass the BarService test.

**SpringApp.java**

```
class FooService {

}

@Component
class BarService {
  private final FooService fooService;

  BarService(FooService fooService) {
    this.fooService = fooService;
  }
}


@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder()
      .sources(SpringApp.class)
      .initializers((ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext>) context -> {
        context.registerBean(FooService.class);
      })
      .run(args);
  }
}
```

**SpringAppTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringApp.class)
public class SpringAppTest {
  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext context;

  @Test
  public void barService() {
    Assert.assertNotNull("The barService should not be null", context.getBean(BarService.class));
  }

  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
    Assert.assertNotNull("The fooService should not be null", context.getBean(FooService.class));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### First solution

The main error here is that the test does not have the initalization logic that the main method has. Solution is to extract the logic from the `initializers` method

```
class MyInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {
  @Override
  public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
    System.out.println("Called initialize");
    context.registerBean(FooService.class);
  }
}
```

and use it in main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  new SpringApplicationBuilder()
    .sources(SpringApp.class)
    .initializers(new MyInitializer())
    .run(args);
}
```

and then use the MyInitializer in the test file through **@ConextConfiguration**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringApp.class, initializers = MyInitializer.class)
public class SpringAppTest {
    // ...
}
```

#### Second (better) solution

Now, this can be cumbersome as we need to reference this initializer in every test, but there is an even better solution. We can create a specific Spring file `resources/META-INF/spring.factories` and put inside of it a reference to the initializer:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=com.acme.orders.MyInitializer
```

After that, we can simplify both the main method

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

and the tests, so that they don't need to always import the initializer.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringAppTest {
    // ...
}
```

Now both the main run process and the tests will have access to all the beans.